# How to get rid of use of an uninitialized value within an 'if' construct using a Perl regex

Tags: perl

How do I get rid of use of an uninitialized value within an `if` construct using a Perl regex?

When using the code below, I get use of uninitialized value messages.

```
     if($arrayOld[$i] =~ /-(.*)/ || $arrayOld[$i] =~ /\#(.*)/)
```

When using the code below, I get no output.

```
     if(defined($arrayOld[$i]) =~ /-(.*)/ || defined($arrayOld[$i]) =~ /\#(.*)/)
```

What is the proper way to check if a variable has a value given the code above?

Comment: Which variable is being used without being defined? `$arrayOld` or `$i`?

Comment: Can you show us the actual error message?

Comment: Use of uninitialized value within @arrayOld in pattern match (m//)

Comment: @JosephWalker [Asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10757963/725418). I told you that using that loop was a bad idea, but apparently you did not listen. I also explained how to merge the regexes to avoid problems like these. What is the point of answering your questions if you do not heed the advice you are given?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if($arrayOld[$i] && $arrayOld[$i] =~ /-|\#(.*)/)
```

This first checks $arrayOld[$i] for a value before running a regx against it.
(Have also combined the `||` into the regex.)

Comment: Two differences from combining the regexes like that: you aren't capturing `$1` if there's a - (fixed by grouping: `/(?:-|\#)(.*)/`) and you will now capture abc instead of def if the input is `"#abc\n-def"`.

Comment: @ysth: You're quite right. From Joseph's earlier posting, however, he's actually not using $1, so the capture in this regex is unnecessary. Using /^-|\#/ would be sufficient, for his earlier case.  Nevertheless, I missed this grouping fix.  Thank you for adding it here.

Comment: As a solution to the specific problem, this is ok. But a safer solution is using `defined($arrayOld[$i])`, since that excludes other false values, such as the empty string or zero. If the OP tries to do `if ($foo && $foo =~ /\d/)`, it will incorrectly exclude zeros, for example.

Comment: @TLP: Yes, excellent suggestion.  The above is a rather localized solution, but I think using `defined`--for the reasons you've given--is programmatically safer. Appreciate your addition here...

Answer (score 1):

From the error message in your comment, you're accessing an element of `@arrayOld` that isn't defined.  Without seeing the rest of the code, this could indicate a bug in your program, or it could just be expected behavior.

If you understand *why* `$arrayOld[$i]` is `undef`, and you want to allow that without getting a warning, there's a couple of things you can do.  Perl 5.10.0 introduced the [defined-or operator `//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Defined-Or), which you can use to substitute the empty string for `undef`:

```
use 5.010;
...
if(($arrayOld[$i] // '') =~ /-(.*)/ || ($arrayOld[$i] // '') =~ /\#(.*)/)
```

Or, you can just turn off the warning:

```
if (do { no warnings 'uninitalized'; 
         $arrayOld[$i] =~ /-(.*)/ || $arrayOld[$i] =~ /\#(.*)/ })
```

Here, I'm using [do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) to limit the time the warning is disabled.  However, turning off the warning also suppresses the warning you'd get if `$i` were `undef`.  Using `//` allows you to specify exactly what is allowed to be `undef`, and exactly what value should be used instead of `undef`.

Note: `defined($arrayOld[$i]) =~ /-(.*)/` is running a pattern match on the result of the [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function, which is just going to be a true/false value; not the string you want to test.

Comment: Actually, looking at your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10762510/8355), this is actually the result of a bug in your program.  When you `splice` out an element, you're still incrementing `$i`.  This introduces two bugs: you don't examine the next element at all, and you wind up walking off the end of the array.

Comment: @cjm: Program bug...  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question narrowly, you can prevent undefined-value warnings in that line of code with

```
if (defined $i && defined $arrayOld[$i]
      && ($arrayOld[$i] =~ /-(.*)/ || $arrayOld[$i] =~ /\#(.*)/))
{
  ...;
}
```

That is, evaluating either `$i` or the expression `$arrayOld[$i]` may result in an undefined value. Note the additional layer of parentheses that are necessary as written above because of the difference in precedence between `&&` and `||`, with the former binding more tightly. For the particular patterns in your question, you could sidestep this precedence issue by combining your patterns into one regex, but this can be tricky to do in the general case.

I recommend against using the unpleasing code above. Read on to see an elegant solution to your problem that has Perl do the work for you and is much easier to read.

### Looking back

From the slightly broader context of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10762510/123109), `$i` is a loop variable and by construction will certainly be defined, so testing `$i` is overkill. Your code blindly pulls elements from `@arrayOld`, and Perl happily obliges. In cases where nothing is there, you get the undefined value.

This sort of one-by-one peeking and poking is common in C programs, but in Perl, it is almost always a red flag that you could express your algorithm more elegantly. Consider the complete, working example below.

### Working demonstration

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;  # given/when

*FILEREAD = *DATA;  # for demo only

my @interesting_line = (qr/-(.*)/, qr/\#(.*)/);

$/ = ""; # paragraph mode
while(<FILEREAD>) {
  chomp;
  my @arrayOld = split /\n/;
  my @arrayNewLines;

  for (1 .. @arrayOld) {
    given (shift @arrayOld) {
      push @arrayNewLines, $_ when @interesting_line;
      push @arrayOld, $_;
    }
  }

  print "\@arrayOld:\n",      map("$_\n", @arrayOld), "\n",
        "\@arrayNewLines:\n", map("$_\n", @arrayNewLines);
}

__DATA__
#SCSI_test         # put this line into  @arrayNewLines      
kdkdkdkdkdkdkdkd
dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkd
- ccccccccccccccc  # put this line into @arrayNewLines
```

### Front matter

The line

```
use 5.10.0;
```

enables Perl’s [`given`/`when` switch statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements), and this makes for a nice way to decide which array gets a given line of input.

As the comment indicates

```
*FILEREAD = *DATA;  # for demo only
```

is for the purpose of this Stack Overflow demonstration. In your real code, you have `open FILEREAD, ...`. Placing the input from your question into Perl’s `DATA` filehandle allows presenting code and input in one self-contained unit, and then we alias `FILEREAD` to `DATA` so the rest of the code will drop into yours with no fuss.

### The main event

The core of the processing is

```
for (1 .. @arrayOld) {
  given (shift @arrayOld) {
    push @arrayNewLines, $_ when @interesting_line;
    push @arrayOld, $_;
  }
}
```

Notice that there are no `defined` checks or even explicit regex matches! There’s no `$i` or `$arrayOld[$i]`! What’s going on?

You start with `@arrayOld` containing all the lines from the current paragraph and want to end with the interesting lines in `@arrayNewLines` and everything else staying in `@arrayOld`. The code above takes the next line out of `@arrayOld` with [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html). If the line is interesting, we [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) it onto the end of `@arrayNewLines`. Otherwise, we put it back on the end of `@arrayOld`.

The statement modifier `when @interesting_line` performs an implicit smart-match with the topic from `given`. As explained in [“Smart matching in detail,”](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) when smart matching against an array, Perl implicitly loops over it and stops on the first match. In this case, the array `@interesting_line` contains compiled regexes that match lines you want to move to `@arrayNewLines`. If the current line (in `$_` thanks to `given`) does not match any of those patterns, it goes back in `@arrayOld`.

We do the preceding process exactly `scalar @arrayOld` times, that is, once for each line in the current paragraph. This way, we process everything exactly once and do not have to worry about fussy bookkeeping over where the current array index is. Whatever is left in `@arrayOld` after that many `shift`s must be the lines we `push`ed back onto it, which are the uninteresting lines in the order that the occurred in the input.

### Sample output

For the input in your question, the output is

```
@arrayOld:
kdkdkdkdkdkdkdkd
dkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkd

@arrayNewLines:
#SCSI_test         # put this line into  @arrayNewLines      
- ccccccccccccccc  # put this line into @arrayNewLines
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, and an even better explanation!  Great use of smart matching.  I suspect you wanted to be the least intrusive on the original code, so you preserved the paragraph mode file reading.  If it were a line-at-a-time read, however, `given ($_)` could be used and the `for` loop omitted, no `split`, and `my (@arrayOld, @arrayNewLines);` before the `while`.  I know you know these things, but I greatly appreciated your solution's elegance and readability, and couldn't resist working with your code. +1.

Comment: @Kenosis There’s a [fourth question in this series](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10644171/123109). My answer there eschews paragraph mode. I left the skeleton alone here in case there’s extra processing we don’t know about.

Comment: Read your response to the fourth question, and enjoy your effective use of smart matching, where I see it especially shine in instances of multiple matches against a single string.  Thought that's why you left the skeleton alone...